# Couldn't match expected type when defining data type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define my own data type containing Odds:

```
data Odd = Odd Integer deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Enum Odd where
  succ x = Odd $ x + 2
  pred x = Odd $ x - 2
```

When I try to compile that, I get:

```
hello.hs:92:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘Odd’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘x + 2’
      In the expression: Odd $ x + 2
      In an equation for ‘succ’: succ x = Odd $ x + 2
   |
92 |   succ x = Odd $ x + 2
   |                  ^^^^^
Failed, no modu
```

I don't understand why haskell expect `Integer` on left hand, don't we define Enum instance called Odd, not Integer?

Comment: `succ` has type `Enum a => a -> a`, so the type of `x` in your definition is `Odd`. `x + 2` is therefore a type error. It looks like you want to do something like `succ (Odd x) = Odd $ x + 2`?

Comment: @Lee `(Odd x)` actually works, but why? As you said `x + 2` gets me a type error.

Comment: The argument to your `succ` implementation has type `Odd`. `succ (Odd x)` matches on the only constructor of the `Odd` type (also called `Odd`). Now `x` has type `Integer` so `x + 2` is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntactically what you here aim to do is **add an `Integer` to an `Odd` object**. Since the addition in Haskell requires the two operands to be of the same type, and the fact that `Odd` is not a `Num` type anyway, thus lets the compiler complain that this is not possible.

You can however obtain the element that is wrapped in the `Odd` constructor, and then process that element. For example:

```
instance Enum Odd where
  succ (Odd x) = Odd (x+2)
  pred (Odd x) = Odd (x-2)
```

We thus here obtain the `Integer` `x` that is wrapped in the `Odd` constructor by pattern matching it with `Odd x`, and then we can process that integer `x` further. For example by adding two to it, and wrapping it in another `Odd` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now. How could I make to work smth like `succ x = x + (Odd 2)`? Is it possible?

Comment: @aryndin: by making `Odd` an instance of `Num` (like you here did for `Enum`.  See here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num

Comment: @aryndin ...but you probably do not want to make `Odd` an instance of `Num`. I'm guessing from the name and the `Enum` instance that you intend `Odd` to only contain odd numbers; but `Num` demands `fromInteger :: Integer -> Odd`, which would let you inject even numbers as well.